# meteor application not running

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have using Windows 7 OS.

I have install meteor that is version Release 0.8.3
I have meteor application, and when i run that application i get following error:

"Problem! This project says that it uses version METEOR@0.9.4 of Meteor,
but you don't have that version of Meteor installed and the Meteor update
servers don't have it either. Please edit the .meteor/release file in the
project and change it to a valid Meteor release."

I also update my meteor but still it will give me same error.
what should i do??

please help.

Thank You.

Comment: Create it on Linux or Mac OS, you won't be able to get full usability with Win7

Comment: you can use nitrous.io,koding.com or codebox.io to program

Comment: install the new meteor for windows version? The latest one is 0.9.0.2 http://win.meteor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'METEOR' from METEOR@0.9.4 in the file .meteor/release file.

Answer (score 0):

Delete  `.meteor/release` file inside your meteor-project folder

Answer (score 0):

from within the project folder:

```
meteor update --release METEOR@1.1.0.2
```

That's for the latest version of meteor.  Or, if you're using a different version of meteor

```
meteor update --release METEOR@[insert version here]
```

check your version with meteor --version